# Selecting all rows created less than 1 second apart

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
create table purchase(
   transaction_id integer,
   account_id bigint,
   created timestamp with time zone,
   price numeric(5,2)
)
```

I think I have a problem where a system is sending me duplicate records, but I don't know how widespread the issue is.

I need a query to select all records created within 1 second (not necessary the same second) that has the same account_id and same price.  So, for example, I would want to be able to find these two records:

```
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| transaction_id |   account_id   |            created            | price |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------+-------+
|          85239 | 80012340116730 | 2014-05-07 15:46:03.361959+00 |  8.47 |
|          85240 | 80012340116730 | 2014-05-07 15:46:04.118911+00 |  8.47 |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------+-------+
```

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: So is this old question answered?

Answer (score 7):

You need to check for existence of a row within a second in *both* directions.
And you need to exclude the row itself from the test:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   purchase p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM  purchase p1
   WHERE  p1.created > p.created - interval '1 sec' -- "less than a second"
   AND    p1.created < p.created + interval '1 sec'
   AND    p1.account_id = p.account_id
   AND    p1.price      = p.price
   AND    p1.transaction_id <> p.transaction_id   -- assuming that's the pk
   )
ORDER BY account_id, price, created;         -- optional, for handy output
```

These `WHERE` conditions are [**sargable**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable), which allows the use of an index on `created`:

```
WHERE p1.created > p.created - interval '1 sec'
AND   p1.created < p.created + interval '1 sec'
```

As opposed to:

```
p1.created - p.created < interval '1 sec'
```

The latter cannot use an index on `created` which may slow down the query with big tables.
Postgres is forced to test all remaining combinations (after applying other conditions). Depending on the selectivity of the other conditions and the size of the table, this may be irrelevant or a moderate to huge performance drain.
With small to medium tables, tests have shown two sequence scans and a hash semi join for either query.

#### Index

The perfect index for the case would be a multicolumn index of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX purchase_foo_idx ON purchase (account_id, price, created)
```

Combinations of indexes on individual columns work well, too (and might have more use cases).

Comment: If you check for existence of a row within a second in _both_ directions you'll obtain doubled result.

Comment: @klin: The point is to find rows within a second. You get each existing row once. Nothing is "doubled". If you only check forward or backward, the first / last row of each cluster is not included in the result.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select *
from purchase p1
where exists (
    select transaction_id 
    from purchase p2 
    where p2.created > p1.created
    and p2.created - p1.created < interval '1 second'
    and p2.account_id = p1.account_id
    and p2.price = p1.price)
```

EDIT:
The query could be very heavy on big table. Consider limit it e.g. to one day:

```
select *
from purchase p1
where 
    p1.created::date = '2014-05-08'
    and exists (
        select transaction_id 
        from purchase p2 
        where p2.created::date = '2014-05-08'
        and p2.created > p1.created
        and p2.created - p1.created < interval '1 second'
        and p2.account_id = p1.account_id
        and p2.price = p1.price)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e7f0/5/0)

Comment: Same here: You are missing the last row from each cluster. You would have to compare the absolute value of the difference to include it: `@(p2.created - p1.created) < interval '1 second'`. But as detailed in my answer, the approach is not very efficient to begin with. Also: `p2.created > p1.created` excludes rows with the same value in `created`, which has not been ruled out in the question.

Comment: Your (helpful!) example is proving my point. Row 2 and 4 are *missing* from the result.

Comment: So are you going to delete all 4 rows? Or only 2 redundant?

Comment: Delete? The request is: `I need a query to select all records created within 1 second`.